# In a three for-each imbricated using Map.Entry<String, Map<Date, List<SomeObject>>> when I iterate why I have a Exception in the second for-each loop?

Tags: java, list, date, dictionary, nullpointerexception

*In a three foreach imbricated using Map.Entry>> when I iterate on the second Map I have a NullPointerException in below code. I can't realize what is the root cause.
To be replicated you need in the project folder to create an "inputData" folder which contain a "data.txt" file with some values like below (I just give some example):*

```
Apahida,15,199,2017-09-03
Apahida,15,249,2017-09-03
Apahida,15,299,2017-09-03
Floresti,7,100,2017-09-01
Floresti,7,250,2017-09-01
Turda,29,149,2017-09-01
Turda,29,199,2017-09-02
```

After that, when I run my main method from MainApp class (see below) I have an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" in the row with the code indicated with a comment below. Can you figured out where is the problem and suggest me a solution, please?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Package> dataPackage = new ArrayList<>();

        File file = new File("inputData/data.txt");
        List<String> listInputData = null;
        try {
            listInputData = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file.getPath()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (String string : listInputData) {
            String[] split = string.split(",");

            Package aPackage = new Package(split[0], Double.parseDouble(split[1]), Double.parseDouble(split[2]), split[3]);
            dataPackage.add(aPackage);
        }

        Map<String, Map<Date, List<Package>>> packagesGroupedBasedOnTargetLocationAndDeliveryDate = new HashMap<>();
        for (Package aPackage : dataPackage) {
            String targetLocationOfPackage = aPackage.getTargetLocation();
            boolean targetLocationExistInMap = false;
            for (Map.Entry<String, Map<Date, List<Package>>> targetLocationInMap : packagesGroupedBasedOnTargetLocationAndDeliveryDate.entrySet()
            ) {

                if (targetLocationInMap.getKey().equals(targetLocationOfPackage)) {
                    targetLocationExistInMap = true;
                    Map<Date, List<Package>> packagesGroupedBasedOnDeliveryDate =
                            packagesGroupedBasedOnTargetLocationAndDeliveryDate.get(targetLocationOfPackage);
                    boolean deliveryDateExistInMap = false;
                    Date deliveryDateOfPackage = aPackage.getDeliveryDate();
                    for (Map.Entry<Date, List<Package>> deliveryDateInMap : packagesGroupedBasedOnDeliveryDate.entrySet()) {

                        if (deliveryDateInMap.getKey().equals(deliveryDateOfPackage)) {
                            deliveryDateExistInMap = true;
                            packagesGroupedBasedOnTargetLocationAndDeliveryDate
                                    .get(targetLocationOfPackage)
                                    .get(deliveryDateOfPackage)
                                    .add(aPackage);
                        }
                    }
                    if (!deliveryDateExistInMap) {
                        List<Package> newListOfPackageByDeliveryDate = new ArrayList<>();
                        newListOfPackageByDeliveryDate.add(aPackage);
                        packagesGroupedBasedOnTargetLocationAndDeliveryDate
                                .get(targetLocationOfPackage)
                                .put(deliveryDateOfPackage, newListOfPackageByDeliveryDate);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println(packagesGroupedBasedOnTargetLocationAndDeliveryDate.toString());
                    System.out.println();
                }

            }

            if (!targetLocationExistInMap) {
                List<Package> newListOfPackageByDeliveryDate = new ArrayList<>();
                newListOfPackageByDeliveryDate.add(aPackage);
                Map<Date, List<Package>> newMapOfPackageByDeliveryDate = new HashMap<>();
                newMapOfPackageByDeliveryDate.put(aPackage.getDeliveryDate(), newListOfPackageByDeliveryDate);
                packagesGroupedBasedOnTargetLocationAndDeliveryDate
                        .put(targetLocationOfPackage, newMapOfPackageByDeliveryDate);
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<Date, List<Package>>> targetLocationSTRING :
                packagesGroupedBasedOnTargetLocationAndDeliveryDate.entrySet()) {

            for (Map.Entry<Date, List<Package>> deliveryDateDATE :
                    packagesGroupedBasedOnTargetLocationAndDeliveryDate
                            .get(targetLocationSTRING).entrySet()) {         /// ***EXCEPTION APPEAR HERE, WHY?***

                for (Package aPackage :
                        packagesGroupedBasedOnTargetLocationAndDeliveryDate
                                .get(targetLocationSTRING).get(deliveryDateDATE)) {
                    System.out.println(aPackage.toString());

                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Thanks. I will replace them.

Answer (score 1):

In the line marked `/// ***EXCEPTION APPEAR HERE, WHY?***` you are doing a `packagesGroupedBasedOnTargetLocationAndDeliveryDate.get()`, passing a `Map.Entry<String, Map<Date, List<Package>>>` as key. However the keys of `packagesGroupedBasedOnTargetLocationAndDeliveryDate` are of type `String`, so we can tell from the start that the key is not found, and that `get` therefore returns `null`. Next you try to call `entrySet()` on this `null`, which gives a `NullPointerException`.

The problem comes from `Map.get()` accepting a key of the wrong type. The reason for this is historic. However your IDE should warn you about it.

Comment: Sounds fair. Thank you.